Summary on Azure Devops build only shows "Get started" under Tests and Coverage on build containing valid code coverage
On other builds I see the following, which is what I want.
The Desired Outcome
This working build uses VSTest
The build I am trying to get code coverage working on is using Npm@1 'run test-with-coverage' to generate coverage, and PublishCodeCoverageResults@2 to publish with summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml'.
I see the code coverage tab with correct coverage data, but on the summary screen I just see "Get started" Undesired Outcome
I've search google and bing, and talked through it with copilot. I upgraded the pipeline from PublishCodeCoverageResults@1, to PublishCodeCoverageResults@2.

I can reproduce the same on my side. The task PublishCodeCoverageResults@2 is used to publish code coverage result not test result.
You can add PublishTestResults@2 task to publish the test result.
Make sure you have test result(TEST-RESULTS.xml) generated at the Npm@1 run test-with-coverage task.
For example, my package.json for npm test task:
{
  "name": "HelloWorld",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Hello World",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "",
    "email": ""
  },
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "nyc --reporter=cobertura --reporter=html ./node_modules/.bin/mocha tests/**/*.js --reporter mocha-junit-reporter --reporter-options mochaFile=./TEST-RESULTS.xml"
  }
}


The yaml sample:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm test'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    customCommand: 'test'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-RESULTS.xml'
    testRunTitle: 'Test results for JavaScript'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  inputs:
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*coverage.xml'


